# Cookie not setting path default to page

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, path

Ater migrating our application, cookies have stopped setting the path to the current page, always setting it to root. Only the `name` and `value` are set using plain javascript (like the example below). The cookie path is not specified, and that should default to the current page. This can be replicated using the console. For example, on the migrated server page `/cat`, if I open the console and run:

```
document.cookies = "foo=bar"
```

Then the path of the cookie is root, not `/cat`.
[image]

On the pre-migration server, the default behavior sets the path to `/cat`.

[image]

Can the server affect the cookie path default behavior?

**UPDATE**
I discovered it is simply ignoring the last part of the path, for example, if I go to the page `/foo/bar/cat` is saves this path by default, which is still not expected.

[image]

Comment: How are you setting the cookies?

Comment: Just like in the example above, only name and value.

Comment: The path of a cookie is the folder, not the filename.

Comment: AFAIK you can't have cookies specific to a particular document, the granularity is folders.

Comment: I was coming to that realization when I found the answer, which I'll post, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I failed to notice that the pre-migration server redirected `/cat` to `/cat/`, which made it a directory that the default path would respect.